# how to get parent with child entries in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am new to MongoDB.
my collections are `authors` and `books`. its many to many associations

my authors collections

```
[{
    "id": "11",
    "name": "Sam",
    "age": 40
},
{
    "id": "12",
    "name": "Jack",
    "age": 20
},
{
   "id": "22",
    "name": "Smith",
    "age": 35
}]
```

my books collections

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "title": "Hello World",
    "price": 200,
    "authors":["Sam","Jack"]
},
{
    "id": "34",
    "title": "Good Day",
    "price": 100,
    "authors":["Smith"]
}]
```

This is my postman result.

```
[{
    "authors": [
        {
            "id": "11",
            "name": "Sam",
            "age": 40,
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "Jack",
            "age": 20,
        }
    ],

    "id": "123",
    "title": "Hello World",
    "price": 200,        
}]
```

I put query in mongo shell to find `books` but result only shown book details not shown `authors`(child entries).

how to I get books with authors entries in mongo shell command(like postman result).

Thanks.

Comment: Please post both the `authors` and `books` document samples.

Comment: Thanks @prasad. I posted authors and books collection samples

Comment: You have to use an Aggregation query using the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to join the two collections and get the result you are looking for. Note that, the data for the books and authors can also be designed (or modeled) as a single collection by embedding; see [Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/) for _one-to-many_ relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    <db>.books.aggregate([
    {
        '$project': {
            'id': 1, 
            'title': 1, 
            'price': 1, 
            'authors': 1, 
            'numberOfAuthors': {
                '$cond': {
                    'if': {
                        '$isArray': '$authors'
                    }, 
                    'then': {
                        '$size': '$authors'
                    }, 
                    'else': 0
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'numberOfAuthors': {
                '$eq': 2
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'authors', 
            'localField': 'authors', 
            'foreignField': 'name', 
            'as': 'authors'
        }
    }
])
```

Used *projection* followed by *match* before *lookup*.

Comment: Thanks.I use this but result shown one book list with all authors list.i want one book list with two authors list(thats my aim of project).please tell how to do this?.

Comment: Use _projection_ for get the size of the array **authors**, then used that to _match_ the required number of authors (_$eq_, _$gte_, etc.) before performing a _lookup_.